# Animation like moving asteroid or attacking fire with CSS/Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-animate, css-animations

I have some blocker on my project. I making a map, which is showing requests between machines. I wanted to show requests like an attack, but I can't find any examples such kind of animation. I did it on canvas window, but I need on my map. The best example is: http://map.norsecorp.com/v1/ 
I have map, and other configurations ready, blocker is only attack animation.

Comment: Nice looking site.  I inspected the html to see that the map is `<svg class='overlay'...>` and the canvas is `<canvas id='visible-overlay'...>`.  The question should be how to convert canvas drawing to svg or how to make an svg effect.

Comment: Thank you wolfhammer, the main issue was how to create that animation on svg or maybe other ways no problem. It's just I have created a map with all needed data, but only I can't find making that animation, I can apply any possible answers.